# clojure refactor code from recursion

Tags: clojure

I have the following bit of code that produces the correct results:

```
(ns scratch.core
  (require [clojure.string :as str :only (split-lines join split)]))

(defn numberify [str]
  (vec (map read-string (str/split str #" "))))

(defn process [acc sticks]
  (let [smallest (apply min sticks)
        cuts (filter #(> % 0) (map #(- % smallest) sticks))]

    (if (empty? cuts)
      acc
      (process (conj acc (count cuts)) cuts))))

(defn print-result [[x & xs]]
  (prn x)
  (if (seq xs)
    (recur xs)))

(let [input "8\n1 2 3 4 3 3 2 1"
      lines (str/split-lines input)
      length (read-string (first lines))
      inputs (first (rest lines))]
  (print-result (process [length] (numberify inputs))))
```

The `process` function above recursively calls itself until the sequence `sticks` is `empty?`.

I am curious to know if I could have used something like `take-while` or some other technique to make the code more succinct?

If ever I need to do some work on a sequence until it is empty then I use recursion but I can't help thinking there is a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your core problem can be described as

1. stop if count of sticks is zero
2. accumulate count of sticks
3. subtract the smallest stick from each of sticks
4. filter positive sticks
5. go back to 1.

Identify the smallest sub-problem as steps 3 and 4 and put a box around it

```
(defn cuts [sticks]
  (let [smallest (apply min sticks)]
    (filter pos? (map #(- % smallest) sticks))))
```

Notice that `sticks` don't change between steps 5 and 3, that `cuts` is a fn sticks->sticks, so use [iterate](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/iterate) to put a box around that:

```
(defn process [sticks]
  (->> (iterate cuts sticks)
;; ----- 8< -------------------
```

This gives an infinite seq of `sticks`, `(cuts sticks)`, `(cuts (cuts sticks))` and so on

Incorporate step 1 and 2

```
(defn process [sticks]
  (->> (iterate cuts sticks)
       (map count)         ;; count each sticks
       (take-while pos?))) ;; accumulate while counts are positive

(process [1 2 3 4 3 3 2 1])
;-> (8 6 4 1)
```

Behind the scene this algorithm hardly differs from the one you posted, since lazy seqs are a delayed implementation of recursion. It is more idiomatic though, more modular, uses take-while for cancellation which adds to its expressiveness. Also it doesn't require one to pass the initial count and does the right thing if sticks is empty. I hope it is what you were looking for.

Comment: nice. must remember iterate, this is much nicer than my reduce.

Comment: exactly what I was looking for.  I have learned something today.

Answer (score 0):

I think the way your code is written is a very lispy way of doing it. Certainly there are many many examples in The Little Schema that follow this format of reduction/recursion.

To replace recursion, I usually look for a solution that involves using higher order functions, in this case `reduce`. It replaces the `min` calls each iteration with a single sort at the start.

```
(defn process [sticks]
  (drop-last (reduce (fn [a i]
                       (let [n (- (last a) (count i))]
                         (conj a n)))
                     [(count sticks)]
                     (partition-by identity (sort sticks)))))

(process [1 2 3 4 3 3 2 1])
=> (8 6 4 1)
```

I've changed the algorithm to fit reduce by grouping the same numbers after sorting, and then counting each group and reducing the count size.